# Why in windows phone development is there ^ rather than *

Tags: pointers, windows-phone-8, direct3d, c++-cx

What is the difference between the ^ and the *...

Is it something to do with how ARM processors deal with pointers.

Should I always be using ref class rather than the usual pointer referenced classes?

What is the problem it is solving?

(In windows phone development do I need to use it)?

Comment: It's just C++/CX syntax (actually just _syntax sugar_ translated to plain C++).

Comment: what is CX? what is C++ CLI? my question got changed by someone to languages I know nothing about. I only know C++

Comment: Well, so first learn C++/CX if you want to use it! :) Anyway you can program Windows Phone even in plain C++

Comment: I thought I was programming this in C++, I didn't realise I was slipping into another language!

Comment: Please note that `C++/CX` is different from `C++/CLI`.

Comment: If the only language you know is C++, then what you are trying to do is to write a program in a language you do not know :) It is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI).

Comment: Thanks Microsoft. We all really needed something (non standard) else...

Comment: @VladLazarenko here probably C++/CX not C++/CLI (they share same syntax for reference counted classes).

Comment: hahaahha. ahhh I C...++. With this new knowledge i'll rule the world. So I see that CLI hands me a C# object for accelerometer for example, so in this case I have to use CLI to interface with it, right? whereas with my own code I have incorporated, I can use the pointers as it does not have to do any downstairs mixups

Comment: Indeed @Adriano. It's worse than that. Early CLI stuff was completely different so everything had to be refactored when some smart alec came up with using `^`.

Comment: @JamesT no, unless you explicitly _asked_ to compile a .NET assembly you're NOT using any C# object but old plain COM objects. That's just the C++/CX syntax to _easily_ use COM objects and reference counting (unfortunately it's same syntax used in C++/CLI too).

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, I think it's one of their worse design decisions. I even had to write (and the rewrite...) a project in that ugly thing that C++ with Managed Extensions was...

Comment: @Adriano: Managed C++, C++/CLI, C++/CX... Microsoft should stop screwing up C++ and coming up with their own languages :-]

Comment: @VladLazarenko I can't agree more. I wonder if effort to reinvent the wheel each time isn't more than follow a f* standard!!!

Comment: Right hangon, stop all the hate. :) If I try and call upon, for example, the device::sensors namespace to access the accelerometer, it does not allow me to make calls to it without using the top hat symbol, so actually in this case, im forced to use the top hat

Comment: @JamesT read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/10/20/10228473.aspx). There is also a plain _old_ native API (same syntax as _desktop applications_). If you don't want CX syntax but you want COM objects and C++ classes start reading [these blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/08/29/cxxcxpart00anintroduction.aspx).

Comment: @JamesT you welcome! It's a pretty big topic to start with!

Comment: @Adriano - oh goody goody <cries> unfortunately I have written 1, yes, 1 game in C++ for desktop and now I want to write a C++ Direct3d game for windows phone... so ultimately I have started to use CX features without even realising it because of my lack of C++ experience. This will surely be a great help for me to making a standard and portable C++ game that can use opengl for other phone platforms.

Comment: @JamesT if you're planning to make it portable across other (mobile) platforms then...good luck!!! Each one has its own APIs and preferred language...

Comment: @Adriano - I will make interfaces to everything I can, hopefully will make life easier when porting (in the future).. but your concern is much understood haha

Answer (score 2):

`^` is a non-standard C++ pointer.

Microsoft use (abuse perhaps) `^` to denote a managed C++ pointer when compiling with CLI.

(CLI - the Common Language Interface - is used to interoperate between pure C++ and bytecode languages like c#).

**This stuff caught on: `^` is used for reference counted pointers in C++/CX.**

Comment: I have seen this before, but not sure I understood the reasoning... is it that for ARM processors, pointers need to be counted? and in x86 they don't, so they helpfully made an interface so you don't have to keep pointer counters? or is this completely wrong?

Comment: But in this case probably he is not writing any managed program then it's just a non-standard syntax for a shared_ptr, syntax sugar for C++/CX. BTW in C++/CLI they're not pointers but handlers (that's why we still need pin_pointer<>() & friends)

Comment: In this case im writing a C++ application for windows phone... I assume I need to use .NET framework because it gives me access to the accelerometer objects etc? I don't know enough about this, all I need to do is.. do I have to use the ^ for windows phone dev or is there a better C++ standard way of doing this? do any of you know?

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now! so my code is not managed because I am in charge of how memory is created and dumped, so actually in this case the top hats are superfluous :D is this right?